# How to Prove that if A ⊂ B then P(B − A) = P(B)−P(A)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Well I'm not sure if this prove is right.

$P(B-A) = P(B)-P(A)$

I think that this prove only function if $A \subset B$, then $P(A) \le P(B)$. If someone could find that is not true I will apreciatted it.

(Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 3):

We have $P(B)=P((B\bigcap\,A^{c})\bigcup\,(B\bigcap\,A)=P(B/A)+P(AB)$ which implies

$P(B/A)=P(B)-P(AB)$ so your statement is true only if $P(AB)=P(A)$ i.e.

only if $A\subseteq\,B$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A\subseteq B$, then we can express $B = A\cup(B - A)$. Since $A\cap(B - A) = \varnothing$, one gets the desired result:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(B) = \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B - A) & \Longleftrightarrow \textbf{P}(B - A) = \textbf{P}(B) - \textbf{P}(A)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!